# How to prevent Parent from passing value to Child until the value is available

Tags: angular, typescript

I know I've to use `@Input()` decorator and I'm doing so. But I'm using an async operation. My problem is that Parent sometimes sends empty or half filled array to the child. Here is my code:

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
...

@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    ...
    months=[]; // this i want to send to child
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

    translateModes(callback): void {
        this.translate
            .get([
                'Monthpicker.Months.January',
                'Monthpicker.Months.February',
                ...
                'Monthpicker.Months.December'
            ])
            .subscribe(translations => {
                this.months.push(translations['Monthpicker.Months.January']);
                this.months.push(translations['Monthpicker.Months.February']);
                ...
                this.months.push(translations['Monthpicker.Months.December']);
                callback(this.months);
            });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.translateModes(data => {
            console.log(data) // Output: Object {January, Feb,.....
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child [allMonths]="months"></app-child>
```

There is some lag, that's why in child component:

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { isUndefined } from 'lodash';
...

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() allMonths:any

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
    console.log("ok let me cross check ", this.allMonths); // undefined
    
  }
}
```

I tried:

1. I tried using `ngIf` in parent template to send the value only if it fully loaded. But my tech lead says it is not cleaner way.
2. Then I added in child component to make sure it is not undefined. Didn't work:

   ngOnChanges() {
   if(!isUndefined(this.directiveOne)) {
   this.passDateLocale=this.directiveOne;
   }
   }

What else I can try? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go with the standard way, I would suggest to go for best user experience. Problem here is not 'Passing the value to component' rather than to be a better user experience.

If you are loading any component on the user screen and that required some data. Two way can be possible, one is put an ***ngIf** check so once the data is available it render the whole component. Another way is to load the component and add a spinner or loader within child component only and till the data is arrived, user will see a loader or spinner. You will find this on most of the web apps.

Coming to possibility of you problem. Angular works like Once a component is parse with **html** and **js**, if you put any child component in the **HTML**, it will pass and render until you use *ngIf directive or any such directive. Because angular gets its **dom** tree and variables bound to it, it rather less care about the value and it render the child component as well.

The value part is on us, may be **async pip** or ***ngIf** or **loader**, these things you can implement. But the point here is what is best suited for your app and user experience.

Comment: How can I use async pipe with directive. I tried this: `[allMonths]="months | async"`. But its not working.

Comment: you have to use it with the template in the child component, not in the input. I guess. The problem here is even if you use async pipe, some delay will be there to show the data, till than component will be loaded with some data or loader ? This is will not solve the actual problem.

Comment: Haan this is one issue with my code. But your answer gave me correct direction. I've enough information to proceed. I'm accepting the answer.